# ad integration problems with cordova 5.1.1 and HTML/canvas/SVG app

Tags: html, canvas, ads

the development team I'm working with is getting showstopping problems when attempting to implement admob/inmobi with our canvas-based HTML5 app. After the first ad fires, the framerate slows down considerably, on both ios and android.  They point to a thread here which implies perhaps a problem with Google. Any ideas for a workaround or any other advice?
https://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/44937-admob-plugin-causes-frame-rate-drop-when-the-ad-cycles/page-3

They also report plugin and other errors when attempting to integrate other ad platforms - mmedia, flurry, and others. Is there no ad platform that might work?

Thanks for any thoughts.